# Is it correct to say "The construction worker laid tiles on the foundation(s) of the house" or "The worker laid tiles on the floor of the house"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In the dictionary, they say

> [lay bricks/carpet/concrete/cables etc](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lay-bricks-carpet-concrete-cables-etc)
>
> to put or fasten bricks, a carpet etc in the correct place, especially
> on the ground or floor
>
> The carpet was laid last week.
>
> The project involved laying an oil pipeline across the desert.

It seems that when we say "**The construction worker laid tiles**", the part "**on the foundation**" or  "**on the floor**" is implied.

But, if you have to make it clear, then

Is it technically correct to say "**The construction worker laid tiles/carpets/ wood on the foundation(s) of the house**" or "**The construction worker laid tiles/carpets/ wood on the floor of the house**"?

Does "**floor**" mean it has already had a layer of carpet or wood or tiles on it?

Also, the noun "**foundation**" is countable.

**Is there just 1 foundation in a house or many foundations in a house? For example, each room has a foundation or what?**

Comment: This is completely unrelated to English, but if you are laying tiles straight on the foundation, you are building the house wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For houses built on stumps the floor is quite distinct from the foundations. For older brick houses it would be more common to speak of the footings or foundations of the brick walls in the plural. This is even the case for a single brick wall which may be build on concrete poured into a single trench.

For a house built on a concrete slab the floor *is* the top surface of the concrete, and the slab itself is the (single) foundation. However it is still often referred to in the plural, and the plural may make literal sense if the slab comprises several sections.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there just 1 foundation in a house or many foundations in a house? For example, each room has a foundation or what?

I am currently in the process of building the fourth addition to my house. Each addition (and the original house) has its own section of foundation, but the house (as a whole) only has one foundation (in American English).

If needed, I might refer to this "section" of foundation or that "part" of *the* foundation, but it's still a singular foundation.

Therefore, I would lay tiles on the "foundation" of my house, not the "foundations" of my house, just like I would lay tiles on the "floor" of my house.

However, my house has two stories, so you might ask "do you have tiles on both floors?" indicating that you're asking about both downstairs and upstairs.

Comment: In my house it is impossible to lay tiles onto the top of the foundation(s). The lowest horizontal surface is the timber floor, which is on joists and bearers supported by stumps. How is your house attached to the ground?

Comment: By "stumps", @Peter, do you mean "posts"? It is also impossible to lay tile on the foundation of my house, as there is a wood sill plate sitting on top and the floor joists rest on that - I was continuing with the OP's question. I am going to put a thin brick _veneer_ on the _outside_ of the cinder block walls of the addition's foundation so they appear to match the actual brick foundation of the rest of the house. This _could_ be considered "tile" but isn't in standard AM-EN. I agree 100% that putting tile on _top_ of the foundation is "odd".

Comment: Also, note [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324940/is-it-correct-to-say-the-construction-worker-laid-tiles-on-the-foundations-of/324969?noredirect=1#comment612293_324940). ;)

Answer (score 0):

A building only has one foundation.

A floor is just the thing people stand on. If it's the bottom of the building, the floor could be the foundation itself, as in any unfinished basement in North America. Otherwise, the floor is whatever material it's made of, like wood sheets.

"Wood" is too generic to "lay". We lay "wood flooring".

Also, countable "carpets" means small individual carpets, which anyone can just put down after the floor is built -- no need to "lay" them. If workers are installing it permanently, like over an entire floor, we use the uncountable "lay carpet" or "lay carpeting".

Otherwise, all your sentences are correct.

Comment: "Foundations" is normally used in the plural...

Comment: Not necessarily in American English, @MikeBrockington. My house has _a_ foundation, but "I knew you before the foundations of the Earth". Usually a building is only considered to have _one_ foundation, even if it's built in multiple sections.

Comment: @MikeBrockington That's not true

Comment: @MikeBrockington Can you give an example --preferably real-world-- of "foundations" in the plural with the meaning of the thing that a single building is built on top of?

Comment: See https://www.superdraft.com.au/trends/4-basic-foundation-types-new-home for a discussion of foundations.

Comment: @Peter Those refer to different types of foundations, or the foundations of several different buildings not just one building. I'm looking for something to back Mike Brockington's claim that "foundation" should be plural, presumably even when referring to a single building.

Comment: @gotube  Try a google search for "how to lay foundations" - the majority of links use the plural, though possibly more so for UK sites?

Comment: @MikeBrockington I'm trying to understand your claim that "foundations" is normally plural. I'm assuming you don't mean it in the trivial sense that it appears more often in the plural because most conversations refer to foundations in the general sense rather than referring to a single one.

Comment: I am saying that almost any sentence in BrE that talks about foundations uses the plural. Phrases like "a solid foundation" are the rare exception. No builder would say that your house has "a foundation" rather he would say that it has "foundations".

Comment: @MikeBrockington I still can't picture it. Please give a trivial example sentence that you consider correct and natural.

Comment: @gotube, many office buildings have reinforced concrete foundations. The foundations of our house are concrete. The bridge pylon has foundations of reinforced concrete piles driven into the ground.

Comment: @Peter Would you use that even if it was a normal house with a single poured concrete foundation layer, or are you picturing a special kind of house with several different parts that form different foundations to different parts of the house?

Comment: @gotube, if I knew the house was built on a single poured concrete slab floor I might use the singular. but I would normally use the plural word. I would normally say "the foundations were cracked by the earthquake" or "the concrete slab was cracked by the earthquake", rather than "the foundation was cracked by the earthquake".